# redirect only home page to a separate page wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In my WordPress multisite, I need need my subsite home page to redirect to a different page. Like site.com/subsite or site.com/subsite/ should redirect to site.com/subsite/home/ .

Redirect 301 can do this but, it will also redirect site.com/subsite/search?q=param1 to site.com/subsite/home/search?q=param1 . But it should not.
wp_redirect will do same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subsite/?$ /subsite/home/
```